# Applying a "theme" class name on <div id="app"> with Vue.js 2.0?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, themes, vue-router

I have an app that mostly contains pages with light text on a dark background. I'd like to be able to specify a class on `<div id="app"></div>` like `<div id="app" class="theme--dark"></div>`. I'm trying to determine the best approach to doing this in a Vue.js 2.0 app.

Would it be best to specify a parameter in `router.js` like `themeLight: true` on pages that should have the alternate theme? Or should this be done in store.js using Vuex?

For example:

```
const router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      name: 'Profile',
      path: '/profile',
      component: Profile,
      themeLight: true
     }
  ]
});
```

How would I need to go about accessing the value of `themeLight` in App.vue to apply it on `<div id="app"></div>`?

Comment: have you taken a look at the css modules? I have yet to use them myself, but they seem like they would do what you want https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/css-modules.html